# What is the syntax used for the syntax specification on the Mozilla Developer Network?

Tags: css, syntax, grammar, mozilla

The MDN [page on @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) describes its syntax as:

```
@font-face {
  [font-family: <family-name>;]?
  [src: [ <uri> [format(<string>#)]? | <font-face-name> ]#;]?
  [unicode-range: <urange>#;]?
  [font-variant: <font-variant>;]?
  [font-feature-settings: normal|<feature-tag-value>#;]?
  [font-stretch: <font-stretch>;]?
  [font-weight: <weight>];
  [font-style: <style>];
}
```

But I don't know how to read such a specification and I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: I think [this may have some relevance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [Value definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the syntax of W3C CSS specs. The definition of the various parts can be found at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#property-defs

In the example above, the ? means the part proceeding is optional, and the | between options indicates either one or the other options must be present, but not both.

Comment: The `#` qualifier isn't covered by that spec. I think it means a list: `<urange># :== <urange> [ ',' <urange> ]*`